# Extratcing the entries using two files in grep in linux

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have two text files as follows:

```
file_1:
12567 1e-3
4567  1e-5
189   22e-4
8743  .365
3456  1e-9

file_2:
BO:0012567
BO:0084567
BO:0004567
BO:0001890
BO:0000189
BO:0007812
BO:0008743
BO:0134568  
BO:0003456
BO:0006789
```

I want to extract entries of file_2 which match exact entries of the first column of file_1. Here is my desired output

```
 output
BO:0012567 1e-3
BO:0004567 1e-5
BO:0000189 22e-4
BO:0008743 .365
BO:0003456 1e-9
```

I tried `grep -f file_1 file_2 > output.txt` in linux but it fetched all the entries with both perfect and partial match. I want only those entries which match perfectly without any number leading or tailing from file_2. Kindly guide me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR  {a[$1]=$2; next} 
      $2+0 in a {print $1 FS $2,a[$2+0]}' file1 FS=: file2

BO:0012567 1e-3
BO:0004567 1e-5
BO:0000189 22e-4
BO:0008743 .365
BO:0003456 1e-9
```

Answer (score 1):

Another for the awk:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next } 
    (b=$0) && sub(/.*:0*/,"") && ($0 in a) { print b, a[$0] }
' file1 file2
BO:0012567 1e-3
BO:0004567 1e-5
BO:0000189 22e-4
BO:0008743 .365
BO:0003456 1e-9
```